# Guess the number game with JQquery

Tags: jquery, numbers

I need to create in javascript a "guess the number game" between 1 and 10..

The page must include 2 text input boxes and 2 buttons. One of them generates the random number and assigns it to a text field. I also must use jQuery to capture the click event and the value of the text field.

Then, I need to compare the value of the inputed number to the generated number and if they match, I have to let the user know. Otherwise tell the user to guess again.

As well, I must change the generated number text field to a "hidden" field (hidden input box).

Anyone may help me?

Many thanks.

---

To check if the field is empty, the code would be next?

```
if(parseInt($("#user_input").val()) == ('')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample JQuery number guess game for you (before you edited your post with your sample codes)

I think that this JSFiddle will help you with JQuery click events, etc.
The same code also includes:
2 input boxes, (one is hidden, another is text).
2 buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/VBNQq/

Also, if you do Math.floor(Math.random()* 11), it will create random number between 0 and 10, so I think you should use

```
Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
```

This should gets you random number between 1 and 10

Comment: To check if the field is empty, the code would be next? `if(parseInt($("#user_input").val()) == ('')`

Comment: Many thanks again! Sorry, but I am new at this platform, so what do yo exactly mean with "if you did like m answer, please make sure to check accept!"?